# swipe scroll snap only one section for every swipe and regardless of swipe speed

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, swipe

I have a horizontal scroll container on which I apply CSS `scroll-snap` properties. However, when I **quickly swipe** right it is possible to **skip** from the first section directly to the **third**, without stopping at the second section.

Is there a way to swipe **only one section** for **every swipe**, regardless of **swipe speed**?

```css
.slider {
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 100%);
  scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
}

.slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.slds {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

.slds:nth-child(1){background: red;}
.slds:nth-child(2){background: orange;}
.slds:nth-child(3){background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slds">1</div>
  <div class="slds">2</div>
  <div class="slds">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out `scroll hijacking`
Here's an example from a quick goodle
https://codepen.io/BandarRaffah/pen/LYPQrEe

Comment: @DonaldDuck 
it works, but i really need to make users feel like they are grabbing the section when they swipe it,
that's why I used the CSS snap scroll method.
i tried some jquery codes by hidding the tird section and make it visible only when user swipe to the seconde section,
but it works only on three section at most.
i'm not good jquery developper, i think there is a jquery method to resolve this.
thank you by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `scroll-snap-stop: always` on the child element (your `slds`).

Your example updated:

```css
.slider {
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 100%);
  scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
}

.slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.slds {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

.slds:nth-child(1){background: red;}
.slds:nth-child(2){background: orange;}
.slds:nth-child(3){background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slds">1</div>
  <div class="slds">2</div>
  <div class="slds">3</div>
</div>
```